# fdcu ylim doesn't work in plot package: hydroTSM - logaritmic y-axis

Tags: r, plot, graph, yaxis

I am trying to plot a flow duration curve with the package **hydroTSM**, using the **fdcu.matrix** function. Unfortunatelly I cannot manage to increase or decrease the y-axis length. I tried it with *ylim=c(lownumber,highnumber)*.

When this didn't work I tried to copy paste the package in R, so that I could run it as a function and adjust it... but the fdcu.matrix unfortunately doesn't run without the *require(hydroTSM)*.

(available at https://github.com/cran/hydroTSM/blob/master/R/fdcu.R)

how can I manually or automatically adjust the ylim to the datarange..?

This a part of my data matrix:

> dput(m.fdc01[1:20,1:5])
>
> structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
>   16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.45, 6.372, 6.372, 6.529, 
>   7.09, 3.8, 8.015, 8.277, 9.361, 10.41, 10.705, 9.548, 8.811, 
>   9.176, 8.631, 8.542, 8.365, 8.189, 8.102, 7.588, 7.42, 7.254, 
>   7.09, 7.008, 6.927, 6.847, 6.767, 6.687, 6.687, 6.687, 6.687, 
>   6.847, 6.927, 1.008, 6.927, 7.09, 7.758, 8.277, 7.929, 7.843, 
>   7.673, 7.588, 7.588, 7.588, 7.588, 7.588, 7.42, 7.42, 8.811, 
>   9.927, 8.631, 8.189, 7.673, 7.42, 7.254, 7.008, 7.008, 17.397, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, 16.782, 15.82), .Dim = c(20L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
>       c("DayOfYear", "1970", "1971", "1972", "1973")))

```
# Plot with multiple flow duration curves & legend:

require(hydroTSM)
fdcu.matrix(m.fdc01[,-1], lband=m.fdc01[,-1], uband=m.fdc01[,-1], sim=m.fdc[,-1], plot=TRUE, 
        main ="FDC station 1LA04:1970-1978", xlab="% Time flow equalled or exceeded", 
        ylab="Q, [m3/s]", ylim=c(1,50),yat=c(0.01,0.02,0.05, 0.1,0.2,0.5, 1,2,5,10,20,50,100),
        bands.col = "white", col=col_matsel, lwd=mat_lwd,leg.txt="",
        leg.cex=0.5,leg.pos="auto",cex.axis=1,thr.shw=FALSE)
 legend("bottomleft",legendtextsel,col=col_matsel, lwd=4, y.intersp=1,bty="n",cex=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel this is a bug. I would recommend that you contact the developer. When `fdcu.matrix()` uses `fdcu()` in the algorithm, `fdcu.matrix()` doesn't give the information of `ylim` to `fdcu()`. You can make the modifid `fdcu.matrix()` easily by copying the original code and deleting only one term.

**Preparation**
Run `fdcu.matrix` and copy the output (i.e., the original code).

**Make your function** (almost all is pasted)
`fdcu.matrix2 <- ""paste""` and delete the argument,`ylim`.

for reference

```
fdcu.matrix2 <- 
function (x, lband, uband, sim, lQ.thr = 0.7, hQ.thr = 0.2, plot = TRUE, 
    log = "y", main = "Flow Duration Curve", xlab = "% Time flow equalled or exceeded", 
    ylab = "Q, [m3/s]", ylim, yat = c(0.01, 0.1, 1), xat = c(0.01, ...
                        ^^^^^ delete!!
```

example

```
require(hydroTSM)

fdcu.matrix2(m.fdc01[,-1], lband=m.fdc01[,-1], uband=m.fdc01[,-1], sim=m.fdc01[,-1], 
      plot=TRUE, main ="fdcu.matrix2_test", xlab="xlab", ylab="Q, [m3/s]", 
      ylim=c(1,50), yat=c(0.01,0.02,0.05, 0.1,0.2,0.5, 1,2,5,10,20,50),
      bands.col="white", leg.txt="", leg.cex=0.5, leg.pos="auto", 
      cex.axis=0.7, thr.shw=FALSE)

  # [note] yat and pretty(ylim) are ylabels

  # [note2 (edited)]
  # when log = "y", ylim[1] is disregarded and 0.01 is used instead of it.
```

[image]